scrollbar is not visible in chrome. how to make it always visible?
how to make the scrollbar always visible in Chrome? it's really annoying that it disappears.
Unfortunately, none of the online methods work
I have macbook sonoma 14.5
Chrome 126.0.6478.127
under: chrome://flags
scrollbar doesn't exist...
please help!
thanks

this isn't a question for stack overflow - this isn't code

If you need the scrollbar to appear on your page, you need to style your page with CSS:
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

The overflow-y property makes the vertical scrollbar always appear. You can replace body in my code with any element you want.

it's not about the website I made, but about Chrome in general, e.g. on Linkedin I don't have a scroll bar.

@MarKil that isn't a question for stack overflow then i fear

It seems that this behavior is controlled by your OS settings. On a Mac, you can adjust it in System Settings -> Appearance -> Show scroll bars -> Always
